# IntelliTrace doesn't work properly once "ngen install ... /profile" is used

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ngen, intellitrace

We're developing an application that greatly benefits from Profiled Native Images of .NET framework. Due to that, during our installation, we're running the following on several .NET assemblies:

`ngen install "ASSEMBLY NAME" /Profile`

Shortly after deploying our application, we've received a complaint that users' IntelliTrace feature in Visual Studio 2010 stopped working. After a short investigation we found that as soon as there is a **Profiling Native Image** of **mscorlib.dll**, IntelliTrace stops working. Also, when it happens, we get the following message in the Event Viewer:

> The TraceLog Profiler detected an NGEN /profile assembly loaded into the process. Such assemblies are not supported. Collection will be disabled.

This is especially troubling since mscorlib.dll is a dependency of any other .NET assembly, which means that using `ngen install ... /profile` on any assembly causes mscorlib.dll to be generated as well.

Below is a simple reproduction of the issue:

1. Create a new console application, set its target framework to .NET 2. Add code as appears in the image and set a breakpoint after SomeFunction.
   [image: Sample code]
2. Set IntelliTrace to "IntelliTrace events and call information"
3. Start debugging. Once the breakpoint is hit you should get the following, correctIntelliTrace:
   [image: Correct IntelliTrace]
4. Stop debugging and exit Visual Studio.
5. Open new cmd.exe in elevated mode
6. Execute: 
   `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen install "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /Profile`
7. Start Visual Studio again and start debugging. The same breakpoint will be hit. This time, however, the IntelliTrace will look the following way: 
   [image: Broken IntelliTrace]
8. To make IntelliTrace run again in the same cmd window:

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen uninstall "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /Profile`

We've also tried to use **/NoDependencies** flag of ngen.exe to add only specific assemblies, without mscorlib, however, it seems that it the flag is ignored - Even though we've executed `ngen install ... /Profile /NoDependencies`, the dependencies are installed: Running `ngen display | find "<profiling>"` reveals that mscorlib is still installed even though /NoDependencies flag was used.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to NGEN uninstall mscorlib /profile, even if there are other ngen /profile assemblies installed?
2. Is there a workaround to make IntelliTrace work correctly after NGen /Profile is executed?
3. Why doesn't the /NoDependencies flag work as expected?

Thank you,
Vitaly Belman

Comment: Erm, how did the deployment of your assembly screw up the user's ngen-ed image of mscorlib?

Comment: @HansPassant (Speaking as Vitaly's colleague) The problem isn't that the **regular** ngen-ed image of mscorlib is tempered with or otherwise touched - it isn't. The problem is that the mere existence of an ngen **/profile** image causes intellitrace to stop working.

Comment: That still doesn't explain it, how did the user get *any* ngen-ed image like that?  Ngen.exe is always run on the target machine.  Better take a look at the installer, I'd guess.

Comment: @HansPassant We do run ngen.exe on the target machine. As Vitaly stated in the beginning of his post, "during our installation, we're running the following on several .NET assemblies: `ngen install "ASSEMBLY NAME" /Profile`"

Comment: Okay, got it.  Better remove that option, your customer seems more interested in debugging than profiling.  Post feedback to connect.microsoft.com to ask for a workaround.  Post the link here, you might get SO users to vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have a similar problem with [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) and the way to fix this is I am told is

```
ngen uninstall "assembly details" /Profile
```

IntelliTrace is probably trying to instrument the libraries in order to perform tracing but it cannot do so as it will not get the [JITCompilationStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230586.aspx) events unless they override the [JITCachedFunctionSearchStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231054.aspx) event.

Best thing is to just uninstall the /Profile scenario assembly on the development machine.

*I know I have sort of re-iterated what you know but I have hopefully supplied an answer as to why it is happening but it is probably not something that you can resolve yourself.*

Comment: I see David Broman gave you the same advice he gave me on the MSDN forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/97f07f2d-4135-4599-94bd-66b358edddb1

Comment: Thanks Shaun, I did learn something new. Regarding just running Uninstall - The problem is that our customers ARE developers. Uninstalling the /Profile assemblies makes everything run slower for my users. Without uninstalling, however, they are unable to use Intellitrace and other profilers. Eventually I gave the user an option from my application UI that allows him to turn on "compatibility mode" that degrades performance but allows Intellitrace to function by running NGen Uninstall.

Comment: A good approach - as a developer myself I have never used the `ngen install /Profile ...` so it is not something I would have encountered in my own profiler writing experiments.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there a way to NGEN uninstall mscorlib /profile, even if there are other ngen /profile assemblies installed?

You could directly remove the native images for mscorlib by deleting/renaming mscorlib's NIC folder. For example, for .NET 4.0 64-bit, the folder location is:

`c:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib`